# Localization of app in WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization

Im in the sticky problem of in need to localize the app for different languages. Googling the topic gave me a lot of sites on the same

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520(v=vs.92).aspx

I'm using the msdn as the reference. I've created the AppResource .resx file, made changes in the .csproj file..
Created a new class called Localizedstrings. but im not able to create an instance

```
private static LoveCycles.AppResources localizedResources
```

infact the AppResources is not recognised by the intellisense. I get an error sayin type or namespace name AppResource does not exist in the namespace. How can i access this resource file?

Im tryin to replace the strings which displays message in the messagebox and not the UI elements?

Where have i gone wrong? no bindings have been used in the app.

Alfah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the localization :) and it works like magic.
all you gotta do is to follow the msdn links for localization.

In most of the sites, they have not mentioned how to replace the variables. Jus in case somebody wants to know, I've done it the following way

For strings in msg boxes,

```
 ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("LoveCycles.AppResources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
 msgResult = MessageBox.Show(rm.GetString("msgBoxStartMonitoringDescription") + "\n" + dtSelDate.ToString("dd - MMM - yyyy"), rm.GetString("msgBoxStartMonitoringHeader"), MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
```

msgBoxStartMonitoringDescription and msgBoxStartMonitoringHeader are defined in my resx file.

and for the UI defined in the xaml

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Average" Height="30" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.statsAvgLengthTBlock, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Width="215"/>
```

statsAvgLengthTBlock is defined in the resx file

:)

happy coding all :D

Alfah